# When updating to Angular 5 I'm getting error: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5

Previously my app was working with Angular 4.4.6. I followed the [guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDwVf.png)
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ to update to Angular 5. I used this:

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

But it didn't work. It would give me an error `no valid target found for rxjs`. So instead, I simply changed the versions in my package.json and ran `npm install` and it worked, but when running npm start, I get the error

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
6456:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

So I deleted my node_modules and did npm install once again, and I still get the same error when running npm start.

Screenshot:[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're not getting an error, you are getting warnings. The application should still work.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: There is nothing that needs fixing. Move on.

Comment: I'm getting the same. Even if it's just a warning, I'd like to know whats going on...

Comment: @Mr.Muh, I added an answer as I was able to fix it yesterday. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know how, but the error was just gone today when I continued my work....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing the webpack.common.js with this:

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
    /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
    root('./src'),
    {}
)
```

Comment: I got the same problem but I have no `webpack.common.js` file. Where should I look?

Comment: This code will break lazy loading of child routes in AOT builds built with @ngtools/webpack. Be sure to move the ContextReplacementPlugin to webpack.dev.js instead. 

(As of Angular: 5.0.2, @ngtools/webpack: 1.8.3, and Webpack: 3.4.1)

Comment: `helpers.root()` is meant to be a function you define. See https://angular.io/guide/webpack.